# Possible to use EF also when DB schema changes are not known?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, embedded-resource

I am implementing a WPF application that embeds SQL Server script files as resource. The requirement is to ship those scripts inside the final .exe file.

The UI allows to execute SQL Scripts entered in a TextArea and targeting a specific DB (the server instance is chosen at the login). In some cases, the target DB might not exist yet, therefore the WPF application will use one of the embedded scripts to create a new one. Tables and their columns can change according to the script version.

Because of this **we were thinking to not use EF as technology, as the DBContext might become obsolete between one version and the next of the scripts (eg. new fields added/removed/renamed)**. The new scripts are generated and, ideally, embedded in the solution by DB guys without the need of any intervention from us (.NET developers). As data layer we implement a custom solution that talks with the DB and has a mapping step to provide Domanin Model entities to the business layer.

Would it be possible even with EF to satisfy the requirements above or is it our approach preferable in this case?

Comment: I think that the strength of EF would be lost if you don't know the schema. You might be able to still execute dynamic SQL-queries, but for that there are much smaller libraries to use. What part of EF would you like to use?

Comment: @smoksnes indeed the changing schema requirement made me opt to skip EF. In an ideal case would have used code-first approach and created a repository as Data Access Layer. This would have saved me the need of making the mapping by my own.